# ffmpeg frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I have several images and I am reproducing them in **78.7ms**, I am creating like the 80s video effect.
But, I am unable to find the correct ms, and those images with the original videos are unsynced.

I dumped the video to images using this command => `ffmpeg -i *.mp4 the80effect/img-%d.jpg`
And now, I have 48622 frames.
The video FPS is 24.

So, 48622/24 = 2025 (±)

I cannot use 2025 ms since those images will load very slow. And the approximate value is 78.7ms per frame/image.

How can I find the correct value? The video duration in seconds is 2026. I have tried all math to find this but I'm failing. How many images (one frame) per ms. Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: How long should each image be shown for?

Comment: For the time of a normal video. The same time.

Comment: 1 image = 1 frame of the video

Answer (score 0):

Frame rate is Frame per second (FPS)

1 sec has 1000ms

Each input frame (image) is 78.7ms such that is 12.7 FPS

The video output is 24 FPS not 23.97 FPS

Then the repetition of each frame will be calculated by ffmpeg if using command

`ffmpeg -r 12.7 -i image_%d.jpg -vf fps=24 out_video.mp4`

which is 24/12.7 = 1.8897 which is quite irregular

Hope I could help you understand your question better.